# resize directive for dygraph onload angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dygraphs

I need to resize my graph inside my tabs. Can anyone tell me how to do this in angular? When i load the first time my graphs didn't show unless i move the window and resize it..  I need for the first time that it loads the graphs and fill the div for that..

```
My directive:

    (function() {
    var app = angular.module('dashboard.view', []);

    app.directive('dygraph', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data    : '=',
                options : '=?'
            },
            template: '<div style="width: 100%"></div>',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.options.width = elem.parent()[0].offsetWidth;
                var graph = new Dygraph(elem.children()[0], scope.data, scope.options);
                /*if(scope.options.title=="Scanning" || scope.options.title=="Bytes" || scope.options.title=="Pakets"){
                    graph.ready(function(){
                        var width = this.graphDiv.clientWidth;
                        if(width==0)
                            width=1129;
                            graph.resize(width,320);
                    });
                }*/

            }        
        };
    });

    app.directive('resize', ['$window', function ($window) {
            return {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div>window size: {{width}}px</div>'
         };

        function link(scope, element, attrs){

            scope.width = $window.innerWidth;

            angular.element($window).bind('resize', function(){

                scope.width = $window.innerWidth;

                // manuall $digest required as resize event
                // is outside of angular
                scope.$digest();
            });

        }

    }]);

})();
```

My problem is when I go to another tab it automatically resizes my graph. If i press <kbd>F12</kbd> it appears, but if I just load the tab my graph have width=0.

For the tabs Summary and Probing If i don't use graph ready in the first time the graph inst loaded. But I cant fix the width and height... i need dynamic values otherwise I was doing:

```
  if(scope.options.title=="Scanning" || scope.options.title=="Bytes" || scope.options.title=="Pakets"){
                            graph.ready(function(){
                                var width = this.graphDiv.clientWidth;
                                if(width==0)
                                    width=1129;
                                    graph.resize(width,320);
                            });
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the known issue in Dygraph.It occurs because of the invisible div,so it is unable to assign width to it.[dygraph onload issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dygraphs-users/ca53q-4uZ7s)

Try to make the div visible from onload OR try to call `.resize()` without any parameters to force a redraw when the popup appears.
Or onload you can give the default height,width.

Similar issues like this ..please have a look into this hope this will help you [dygraph1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337417/dygraphs-div-not-visible-until-browser-inspection-window-opened-or-browser-resiz) , [dygraph2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260579/resizing-tabbed-dygraph-window?rq=1)

Comment: If i do that fixing the graph values on graph.resize when I change the tabs the values arent persisted...

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this putting on controller a trigger to the resize event :

```
$timeout(function () {
   window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
});
```